# Pass argument to event handler in Ember handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to reuse the same action for focusing an input field in and out, passing it e.g. true or false as an argument, instead of writing two actions. I can't work out how to pass arguments in, though; is it possible?

E.g. `{{input focus-in="toggleSomething true" focus-out="toggleSomething false"}}` is how I expected it might work, but no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't pass an argument in like that, the only parameter passed through to the action is the current value of the text field.

You can see this if you look at the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.8.1/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L123) for the focusIn function, which calls the local [sendAction](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.8.1/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L170) function that in turn calls [Ember.Component.sendAction](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_sendAction) passing in the "value" variable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct use for this but I managed to pass argument values through to the action like this -

```
{{input focus-in=(action "toggleSomething" true) focus-out=(action "toggleSomething" false)}}
```

I am using Ember 1.13.0